# Javascript - for loop iterates only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a *for* loop but it gets executed once where it should execute two times.

The **$appointments** variable holds the returned data from an ajax call. When I **console.log($appointments.length)** I get two which is correct but the iteration happens only once and I can't figure out why.

```
       for (var i = 0; i < $appointments.length; i+=1) {

          var rangeStart_hour = $appointments[i].timerange.substring(0, 2); 
          var rangeStart_minutes = $appointments[i].timerange.substring(3, 5); 
          var rangeEnd_hour = $appointments[i].timerange.substring(11, 13); 
          var rangeEnd_minutes = $appointments[i].timerange.substring(14, 16); 
          var rangeS = rangeStart_hour + rangeStart_minutes; 
          var rangeE = rangeEnd_hour + rangeEnd_minutes; 
          var rangeStart = parseInt(rangeS); 
          var rangeEnd = parseInt(rangeE); 
          var range=0;

          if(parseInt(rangeStart_hour) == 12){
            if(parseInt(rangeStart_minutes) == 0){
              range = rangeEnd - 0; 
            }else{
              range = rangeEnd - (parseInt(rangeStart_minutes)+20); 
            }
          }else{
            if(parseInt(rangeStart_minutes) == 30 && parseInt(rangeEnd_minutes) == 0){
              // if start time 1:30 ,end time 3:00
              range = (rangeEnd - (rangeStart + 20)); // 300 - 150 = 150
            }else if(parseInt(rangeStart_minutes) == 0 && parseInt(rangeEnd_minutes) == 30){
              range = ((rangeEnd+20) - rangeStart);
            }else{
              range = rangeEnd - rangeStart;
            }
          }

          console.log(range);

          for(var i=1; i<(range/50); i++){
            $("a[data-time='"+(rangeStart)+"']").addClass('time');
            rangeStart += 50;
          };
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This structure seems like a bad idea:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $appointments.length; i += 1) {
    //...
    for (var i = 1; i < (range/50); i++){
        //...
    }
}
```

You *probably* want to use different variable names for your nested loop counters.

Comment: jesus i think i need some sleep.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't have this problem if you compartmentalized your code and avoided performing all your logic in one motherload of a function like that.

Comment: side-note, the `let` keyword could also solve this, once browser support for it is more widespread.

Comment: @Jan yeah i am just prototyping right now but i should make it a habit to compartmentalize.

Answer (score 5):

You reinitialize the variable `i` in the second for loop, if you change

```
for(var i=1; i<(range/50); i++){
    $("a[data-time='"+(rangeStart)+"']").addClass('time');
    rangeStart += 50;
};
```

to use a different variable, say `j` it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, the scope of variable is function scope. It means that all variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the function.
So, in your case:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $appointments.length; i += 1) {
    ...
    for (var i = 1; i < (range/50); i++){ 
        ...
    };
};
```

equals with

```
var i; // two variables with the same name are hoisted as the same variable.

for (i = 0; i < $appointments.length; i += 1) {
    ...
    for (i = 1; i < (range/50); i++){ 
        ...
    };
};
```

So, at the end of the second loop, "i" will be greater than or equal to range/50. If this value is not less than $appointments.length, the first loop will terminate after the first round.

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** JavaScript does not have block scope. Variables introduced with a block are scoped to the containing function or script, and the effects of setting them persist beyond the block itself. In other words, block statements do not introduce a scope. Although "standalone" blocks are valid syntax, you do not want to use standalone blocks in JavaScript, because they don't do what you think they do, if you think they do anything like such blocks in C or Java.

*In your code the **"i"** variable used twice, So second time initialized value is Incrementing in first **for** loop. That's why, Condition failed in first **for** loop and loop is terminating.* Change the variable name in second or first **for** loop then it will be working as you expected